# Create correlation result from tidyverse

Tags: r

I have some of correlation with tidyverse

```
data %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  cor
```

output:

```
              age height      income
age     1.00000000     NA -0.00100384
height          NA      1          NA
income -0.00100384     NA  1.00000000
```

I want to visualize this cor..any suggestion?

Im trying with `corrplot` but it didnt work.

Comment: Hi! Can you make a reproducible example? What's `data` like? Why `corrplot` didn't work?

Comment: 'data' is OKcupid dataset from [link](https://www.reddit.com/r/datasets/comments/4ikzsu/osf_the_okcupid_dataset_a_very_large_public/).

Comment: x<-data %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  cor

corrplot(x,method = "number")

Comment: See my answer, change `mtcars` with `data`. You're missing a pipe `%>%`

Comment: missing argument to function call: if i write this code: data %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  cor(.,use="complete.obs") %>% # we make the correlations
  corrplot::corrplot(,method = "number") # call to corrplot function

Comment: you need to use the `.` (dot) before `,` in `corrplot`

Comment: Ok. But the negative value still didnt appear..

Comment: They are probably too long use: `mtcars %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  cor(., use="complete.obs") %>%
  round(., 3) %>% 
  corrplot::corrplot(., method="number")
`

Comment: Or you can add this parameter `number.cex = 0.8` in the `corrplot` call to make the text smaller (`corrplot::corrplot(., method="number", number.cex = 0.8)`)

Comment: still the negative value didint appear. i dont know why

Comment: have you tried the second solution? make the 0.8 smaller.

Comment: check my updated answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
mtcars %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  cor(., use="complete.obs") %>% # we make the correlations, only on complete.obs
  round(., 3) %>%  # this just rounds up the numbers, we can remove it
  corrplot::corrplot(., method="number") # call to corrplot function
```

[image]

**Note** that if a *correlation is small*, the font color will be *almost white*. Play around with color options to adjust it.

Comment: result are like this. [link](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/27078712/46136016-ee851b00-c246-11e8-9e4b-53314cf68e0f.PNG)

Comment: age height      income
age     1.00000000     NA -0.00100384
height          NA      1          NA
income -0.00100384     NA  1.00000000

Comment: I just wanna visualize my result in simple way. but the result in corrplot isnt good

Comment: You have `NAs` in your original dataset? The plot you get is correct based on your output.

Comment: result are like this: 'Error in cor(., na.rm = T) : unused argument (na.rm = T)'

Comment: Error in cor(., na.rm = TRUE) : unused argument (na.rm = TRUE)

Comment: super. it works. can I change the type of visualization with number?

Comment: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/corrplot/vignettes/corrplot-intro.html follow this guide, you can change almost everything.

Comment: data %>% 
  select_if(is.numeric) %>% 
  cor(.,use="complete.obs") %>% # we make the correlations
  corrplot::corrplot(data,method = "number") # call to corrplot function. it didnt work

Comment: no need to specify `data` in the `corrplot`, because you're using the pipe operator

Comment: It works. but why the negative values of income and age correlation dont appear. or maybe do you have another possibility to create visualizing of the result of my correlation:

Comment: age height      income
age     1.00000000     NA -0.00100384
height          NA      1          NA
income -0.00100384     NA  1.00000000